# Imageview is not visible when i set as src menu item of toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, menuitem

I am so confused to see one thing over here why image view is not visible when i write `

> android:src="@drawable/profile_icon"

but imageview is visible in menu item when i set background to it like

> android:background="@drawable/profile_icon"

Is it because i have taken image in xml toolbar? please help me to set this one.

here is my XML please help me with this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/etfields"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#050b1f"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp"
                    android:text="My T-Shirt"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/logout"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/logout_icon"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp"
                    android:text=" "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/notification"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/notification_icon"
                    android:paddingRight="45dp"
                    android:text=" "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileww"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="@drawable/profile_icon"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you add an image of toolbar with image?

Comment: check your profile icon color its same as your tool bar i think

Comment: place that imageView  as a first child view of your RelativeLayout inside collapsing toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this line in your `imageView` it will work

```
android:paddingRight="40dp"
```

because `background` doesn't affected with `paddding` but when u set `scr`  it will affect.

Your image `width` and `height` is `25dp` and you set `padding` as `40dp`

Comment: Oh!! buddy how could i forget this you saved me, Thanks Anil

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the resolution of your image might be more than the space in which it is inflated. Try using the '`android:scaleType`' attribute, set it to '`centerCrop`'. Your image might be visible after that.